# How to pass value to attribute in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, parameters, conditional, attribute

I have an attribute which I want to pass to a visualforce component, how do I achieve this. Currently I get the error: expecting a boolean

```
Photoshoot="{!IF(!opportunity.Quote__r.Photoshoot__c!='','Photoshoot','')}"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A merge expression starts with `{!` and ends with `}`.
Inside the expression, you don't need to use `{!` any more to pull in properties from the controller, and `!` is specifically the boolean "not" operator.

Evaluation generally happens left-to-right, and `!` has pretty high precedence, higher than `!=` does, so the first bit that gets evaluated is `!opportunity.Quote__r.Photoshoot__c`

If `Photoshoot__c` isn't a checkbox, then you won't be able to apply "not" to it. This explains the error you're getting.

I suspect this is just a simple mistake on your part. Getting rid of that stray `!` should be enough to resolve the error, but I suspect you'll still have a *semantic* error.

From emperical testing, strings in SObjects don't store an empty string. Instead, they store `null`. Things can get a little more complicated if you have the string in memory though. In the end, the proper approach here is to use `ISBLANK()` instead of checking for an empty string (and null).

`{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(opportunity.Quote__r.Photoshoot__c)),'Photoshoot','')}`